# Display a custom notice before all default notices in Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I use the following below code for show custom message to un-logged woocommerce users (visitors) in checkout page

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'my_custom_message');
function my_custom_message() {
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
       wc_print_notice( __('This is my custom message'), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

top code recive this forum, from mr @loictheaztec
my before question link below:
[Display a custom message for guest users in Woocommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126758/display-a-custom-message-for-guest-users-in-woocommerce-checkout-page)

I would like to change **woocommerce_before_checkout_form** in code for move my message to top (first) in checkout page. But I have no idea how to do it.
I only know those two hooks below *(related to checkout page)*:

- `woocommerce_before_checkout_form`
- `woocommerce_after_checkout_form`

[image: i added picture of my problem]

Comment: I think what you need is to do template override. Override the default of woocommerce and create your own, which offers more functionality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To display Your custom message in checkout page before the Woocommerce login message and before add coupon message, you will use the following code instead:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_custom_message');
function my_custom_message() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('This is my <strong>"custom message"</strong> and I can even add a button to the right… <a href="%s" class="button alt">My account</a>'), get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) ), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

A more simpler version **for all users** in checkout page only:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_custom_message');
function my_custom_message() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        wc_add_notice( __('This is my custom message'), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: thank you. work correctly. if i convert this code for show my custom message to all website users (logged and unlogged) What should I do?

Comment: You should just remove `! is_user_logged_in() && ` from the if statement...

Comment: +1 - you've really been crushing it on SO! Nice!  As a note - I've _stopped_ recommending putting functions like this in the theme's `functions.php` file, and instead have started recommending creating a small plugin that contains the "special requirements" of a given site, to ensure a site would survive a theme update or change.

Comment: @cale_b … Thanks. **Note:** There is multiple ways when customizing Woocommerce. But **always use a child theme** *(usefull to override woocommerce templates and some other themes files)* and it survives to the updates. Now **plugins are more difficult to handle**, so using function.php file in a child theme is just fine for most users.

Comment: @ahmadsh I have added a simpler code notice for all users in checkout page at the end of my answer… It will work.