# Avoiding error 500 when duplicating hooked functions in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

if i use 2 codes in functions.php file. recive error 500 !

use below code for buttom checkout page custom message:
[Display a custom message for guest users in Woocommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126758/display-a-custom-message-for-guest-users-in-woocommerce-checkout-page)

and use below code for top checkout page custom message:
[Display a custom notice before all default notices in Woocommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138649/display-a-custom-notice-before-all-default-notices-in-woocommerce-checkout-page)

if i use together. first (1st link) code for buttom page message and two code (2nd link) for top. cant work together. please help me.

Comment: Is there any way we can use two of them for two different messages in the bottom and top?

Comment: Each function need to have a unique name… after all **you can change hooks** to feet your needs (but `wc_add_notice()` is used in `template_redirect` hook and `wc_print_notice()` in the other hooks), *or merge the code in one unique function (as added in my answer)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want multiple hooked functions (duplicated or not), each of them need a unique unused name:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_custom_message_one');
function my_custom_message_one() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        wc_add_notice( __('This is my 1st custom message (for all)'), 'notice' );
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'my_custom_message_two');
function my_custom_message_two() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wc_print_notice( __('This is my custom message (for non logged users)'), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Or you can use one function and 2 notices merged in the same function:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_custom_message');
function my_custom_message() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        wc_add_notice( __('This is my 1st custom message (for all)'), 'notice' );
    }

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        wc_add_notice( __('This is my 2nd custom message (for non logged users)'), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]